# Vertical Scroll using CSS - Background color not working

Tags: html, css, background

I am trying to change the background colur of a div element which should be scrollable. I found out by browsing that there is a method by changing the style in css. But when trying I found out that the background color did not change for the whole scroll. 
Is there a way to fix it. The code I wrote was

```css
div {
  background-color: #673
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow-y: auto;">
  <p>hello world thisvhcdgbcssfcggddcbjyhjkkkjhgbhhbcdcvbhgvbhhvbjgvv</p>
  <pre class="prettyprint linenums">
   <code class="lang-python">
import json
json.dumps(d,indent=9
import math
print("Doo nothing.               j        jkkhhhbjkjhjjkkkkbhhjnhjjklk")
for i in range(1,70):
   print(i)
   </code>
   </pre>
</div>
<p>hello</p>
```

When I open this code I found while scrolling I found it didn't change background colour.
Please help me I need to change the background color of all the scrollable part.[image]. I want the scroll to fully change that green colour.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your css:

```
body {
  margin: 0
}
```

This removes the 8px margin that is applied to the body.

Another option is to add this css to your `div` that is the scrollable section:

```
margin-left: -8px;
margin-right: -8px;
```

Comment: I am not asking for removing the margin. When scrolling through a div element the background doesn't change fully.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve then. You want to change the background color on scroll? You define `background-color:#673` but not to what you want to change it to?